# Home edition: Updates and installing it on a new computer

Tags: licensing, home-edition

I cannot find any info concerning the [Home Edition](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica-home-edition/) on the eligibility

- to receive updates (so e.g. from 9.0.0 to 9.0.1)
- to install it on a more than one computer or on a new computer (I am planning to buy a new one in due time).

Could you give me some references or user experience?

Comment: a) When I moved computer, WRI were very quick and helpful in giving me a new password and download link etc. b) I bought it when 8 came out; I did not get an upgrade to 8.0.4, but got one to 8.0.1

Comment: There is probably some kind of EULA available, most certainly once you install *Mathematica* you´ll have to agree to some terms. I´d say parallel use on different machines will not be allowed, but upgrading or changing a machine for good should work. Probably only WRI will be able to answer your question authoritatively...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue some time ago: no information was obtainable online, I ended up going trough WRI's user portal. There is a support portal there that I used. I described my problem in the greatest detail and after a few working days I got a response. The email conversation which followed ended up with them giving me a new license that I could use on my new system.*

For [buying](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/how-to-buy/industry-individuals.html), you can just go here and select the home edition. You also have the option for upgrading from a previous version.

*My system was the same but with a new OS, Win 8, and a new SSD.

I think the home edition license is limited to use on one computer.

Answer (score 3):

http://support.wolfram.com/kb/717

"To reinstall software from Wolfram Research on a new computer, please use the System Transfer Form."